# Navigation sub-menus

Tags: 7, routes

I'm using the "navigation" menu as my admin menu. I want to create a "report" menu link with sub-menu links for "report - content", "report - comments", "report - users". A view is generating those.

What I would like to do is not show those sub-menu links in the navigation menu. I can do that by unchecking "Show as expanded" for the "report" menu link.

What path do I have to enter for "report" that will show the sub-menus. Do I have to code that?

Comment: Could you just add a dummy piece of content to link the parent menu item to, and position the sub-links under that?

Comment: yeah, I tried that. I has to be a valid path. At least it will expand the menu then. I guess there is no built-in page to show the sub-menus like it does for the "Add Content" menu. admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation/list comes close

Comment: No I don't think there is; there's [`system_admin_menu_block_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_admin_menu_block_page/7) which is the menu callback for a lot of the top level admin pages, but that would mean some coding